# find occurence of a character

Tags: javascript, string

find consecutive occurrences of 1

say i have an string

```
var str = "11101111110";
```

so my result would be

from   0**11111**10**11111**10

to        0**11111***0*10**11111***0*10

can anyone help my generate a code that would get that result?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace it using regex

```js
var str = "011111101111110";
str = str.replace(/(1{5})/g, '$10');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "011111101111110";
 var count  = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    
    if(count == 5){
      str = str.substring(0,i) +"0"+str.substring(i);
    }
    if(str.charAt(i) == 1){
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
 } 
   if(count == 5){
       str = str + "0";
    }

 console.log(str);
```